# secure a rest web service using jersey

Tags: security, rest, jersey

I have implemented rest web services for my application. Since this should not be a public service ,I want to enforce some type of client authentication. Please throw light on how to do that.

FYI, I am using apache Tomcat 7 and a MYSQL database

Comment: You have a lot of options here - anything from container managed security (basic or digest) to [Shiro](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/04/18/apache-shiro/) or [Spring Security](http://blogs.justenougharchitecture.com/?p=493).

Comment: Added that comment as an answer so you can close the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of options here - anything from container managed security (basic or digest) to [Shiro](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/04/18/apache-shiro/) or [Spring Security](http://blogs.justenougharchitecture.com/?p=493).