# Securing Jersey rest service

Tags: security, oauth, jersey

I have developed Restful service using Jersey. The services basically deals with credit card information. 
I want to add security on top of it. I just need the credit card information to be send securely to server. There is no DB to validate any user.

I checked Jersey oauth but not able to understand anything. I need help in securing my web service.

**Update:**

I do not need any user based authorization. I need send data(in XML format) with encryption and in server i want to decrypt it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481539/secure-a-rest-web-service-using-jersey/12497945#12497945 and you'll need to be sure that you're using `https` for your endpoint.

Comment: The example shows authorization based on user role. But how the data is send securely to server

Comment: Use `https` to secure the data transfer. This configuration varies for different containers. Here's documentation for tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html